# Can different threads access different independent methods of the same object at the same time in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say we have 2 threads, and one object with 2 methods. 
Thread 1 uses method1.
**While method1 used by thread 1 is still running**, can thread 2 use method2?

All of this assuming the object was not built with multithreading in mind (no synchronize or similar), and the methods do not access the same variables.

this code suggests that it is possible:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class multithreadaccess {

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass();

        // invokes not sync method
        FirstThreadRunnable ftr = new FirstThreadRunnable(tc);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(ftr);

        // invokes the sync method
        SecondThreadRunnable str = new SecondThreadRunnable(tc);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(str);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        System.in.read();
    }


    public static class TestClass {

        private int callCount = 0;

        public void secondmethod() {
            System.out.println("second method activated! Call number:" + " [" + callCount++ + "] from thread: "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        }

        public void firstmethod() throws InterruptedException {
            // Test with the sleep
            System.out.println("starting first slow method from thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            Thread.sleep(1000); // hold the monitor for 5sec
            System.out.println("stopping first slow method! Call number:" + " [" + callCount++ + "] from thread: "
                    + Thread.currentThread().getId());

            // Test with spinning
            /*
             * System.out.println("MAKE IT SPIN! from thread: " +
             * Thread.currentThread().getId()); boolean spin = true;
             * while(spin){
             * 
             * } System.out.println("IT STOPPED SPINNING! from thread: " +
             * Thread.currentThread().getId()); }
             */
        }
    }

        // invokes the not sync method
        public static class FirstThreadRunnable implements Runnable {
            TestClass tester = null;

            public FirstThreadRunnable(TestClass tester) {
                this.tester = tester;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    tester.firstmethod();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        // invokes the sync method
        public static class SecondThreadRunnable implements Runnable {

            TestClass tester = null;

            public SecondThreadRunnable(TestClass tester) {
                this.tester = tester;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                tester.secondmethod();
            }
        }
    }
```

modified code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662065/can-two-threads-run-two-different-methods-at-the-same-point-of-time)

I do not understand how this is possible, though. I was always thinking an object is linear code. But this suggests that linear is only the code within the methods(As long as no variables are used by multiple methods)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem of your code is the 2 methods `firstmethod` and `secondmethod` are not as "independent" as you thought, because both have `callCount++`.

This may create [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), because both thread are updating that variable. You need to use `AtomicInteger` instead of int, then the code will work.

Edit:
In general, synchronization mechanism ("automatic blocking") is not enabled by default, because these operations are expensive and slow down the program. That's why Java provides `synchronized` keyword as well as threadsafe classes such has `AtomicInteger` to ensure proper access to shared variables and critical sections.

Comment: You are right that there is indeed a shared variable and this could cause a race condition, but this makes it even more diffficult for me to understand because the code works(aside the callCount situation) in the sense that it starts the first method, starts the second method and ends it, and then ends the first method. I always thought that there would be some automatic blocking (no access to one method while another from the same object runs) but there is none? Meaning that any thread could execute any method of any object at any time?

Comment: @harbun No there is no "automatic blocking" as you decribed. this is precisely why classes like `AtomicInteger` exist

Comment: "automatic blocking" , usually implemented through locking or `synchronized` keyword, is not by default because these kind of operation is expensive and slows down the program.

Comment: That clears it up for me, Thanks! Could you add your last two comments to your answer?